# Поиск утечек дескрипторов

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть ли в виндовом CRT средства для поиска незакрытых дескрипторов объектов (файлов, сокетов, процессов и т.п.)

Например для поиска утечек памяти существует способ (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019).

Для поиска утечек дескрипторов можно сделать макрос, оборачивающий каждый вызов функций открытия и закрытия дескрипторов в вызов функции и инкремента/декремента счётчика, но это решение пока выглядит громоздким и сложно будет обернуть всё множество функций открывающих дескрипторы

P.S. не уверен насколько вопрос относится к с++, если что метку могу удалить

Comment: Из гугла: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2011/12/19/how-to-troubleshoot-a-handle-leak/

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, это решение скорее всего на вызове GetProcessHandleCount, которое позволяет оценить общее состояние (текут дескрипторы или нет), даже есть утилита от руссиновича, которая покажет какие именно дескрипторы текут, но проблема получить контекст утечки в коде. Если сделать свою обёртку, то можно сохранять данные о вызывающем контексте вплоть до номера строки файла

Comment: сам не пользуюсь, а статью просматривал по диагонали,так что могу заблуждаться, но вроде как способ с windbg позволяет получить backtrace'ы — это уже фактически строка кода... Собственно тут обёртки, которые как-то вторгаются в код вроде CRT будут абсолютно излишни — дескрипторы это внешний ресурс, так что любой программируемый отладчик позволит отследить всё что с ними происходит без каких-то особых накладных расходов... ЗЫ: в большинстве случев не закрывать дескрипторы файлов перед выходом — нормальная практика...